# Strong convergence of Spectral Projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B(H)$ be the space of all bounded linear operators on $H$.

Assume that $\{A_n\in B(H)\}_n$ strongly converges to $A$.

$E^{|A|}(1,\infty)$ is a spectral projection of $|A|$.

My question is:
does  $E^{|A_n|}(1,\infty) \rightarrow _{so} E^{|A|}(1,\infty)$ or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)\,I$. Then $A_n\to I$ in norm (and so, also strongly). We have
$$
E^{|A_n|}(1,\infty)=I,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ E^{|A|}(1,\infty)=0.
$$

Comment: THX， I saw it is a famous theorem from F. Rellich 1936 math. ann.  saying that except 1(the point spectrum), the statement is true.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: what statement is true?

Comment: when 1 is not in the point spectrum, it is convergent.  Also see W. Bade, weak and strongly limites of spectral operators, pacific j. math. 1954. below theorem 2.6 .

Comment: I see. It makes sense.